# Rails Error uninitialized constant Assignment::AssignmentsCourse in Has Many Through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, nameerror

I'm getting the error "uninitialized constant Assignment::AssignmentsCourse".  Here are my models:

---

*assignment.rb*

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assignmentsCourses
    has_many :courses, :through => :assignmentsCourses
    attr_accessible :name, :dateAssigned, :dateDue, :description, :weight, :category_tokens
    attr_reader :category_tokens

    def category_tokens=(ids)
        puts 'el ids: ', ids.split(",")
        self.courseIds = ids.split(",")
    end
end
```

---

*course.rb*

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :assignments
end
```

---

*AssignmentCourse.rb*

```
class AssignmentCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :assignment
    belongs_to :course
    attr_accessible :assignment_id, :course_id
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
has_many :assignmentsCourses
```

This and all of your fields should not be camel cased it is not ruby style and it breaks the class loading.  The end should only be pluralized too, not both words.  Behind the scenes activerecord depluralizes the symbol you provide and does class loading similar to `require`.  If you tried `require 'activeRecord'` that would not work for example.  Ruby uses underscores to derive multi word class names.

It should be:
`has_many :assignment_courses`

Change the has many though too.  Your accessors should not be camel cased either ruby_style_is_to_underscore.